In ArcGIS Pro, multiple line features (water main) were unknowingly created on top of each other. How?
I help manage the public works GIS database for our water infrastructure. Someone noticed that there had been 5 new main (line feature) insertions and that these all existed one on top of the other.
First of all, it doesn't make sense that this main (line) would have been created at this location, let alone 5 of them one on top of the other.
I've just switched over to using ArcGIS Pro (from Desktop), so I'm wondering if there is some sort of shortcut, or something, that I am unknowingly activating while editing that would cause this to happen.
I have spent the past 5 years helping to clean up this database, so if I am accidentally adding in more errors, I need to figure out how this is happening so I can prevent it from happening again.
Any thoughts how this could have happened?

Select record, copy, and paste in the Edit menu?
